# Custom context menu including a contentpresenter with binded content dependency property doesnt show content in second window

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a custom context menu ExtensibleContextMenu

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ExtensibleContextMenu" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}" x:Shared="False">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ExtensibleContextMenu}">
                    <DockPanel >
                          <ContentPresenter/>
                    </DockPanel>
             </ControlTemplate
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

with the attached dependency property ContentProperty

```
public class ExtensibleContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content",
            typeof( object ),
            typeof( ExtensibleContextMenu ) );

    public object Content
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue( ContentProperty );
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue( ContentProperty, value );
        }
    }}
```

The content property is set in a different style.

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ExtensibleContextMenu}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:ExtensibleContextMenu}}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="400"/>

    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ComboBox/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

The styled ExtensibleContentControl is used in a view, that can be opened twice. It is opened by default in the main window. There anything is working right.

Furthermore it is possible to open this view in another window.

When i open the other window, the extensibleContentControl in the main view looses its content and the content presenter doesnt show anything in the main window.
Furthermore the visual tree under the content presenter in the main window is empty.

Anyone an idea where this problem can come from? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the actual content element as a resource with `x:Shared`:

```
<ComboBox x:Key="theContent" x:Shared="false">
    <ComboBoxItem>item...</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

...and set it in the `Style` using a markup extension:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ExtensibleContextMenu}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:ExtensibleContextMenu}}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource theContent}" />
</Style>
```

A single element can only appear once in the visual tree.

Comment: THANK YOU! That solved the problem. I made a edit to my question to make this question more reusable.